# unable to take screen shot using webdriver

Tags: selenium

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.file.File;

public class Gmail_login {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http:\\google.com");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("D:\\google.png"));

        driver.quit();
        driver.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: FILE cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: The constructor File(String) is not visible    these errors i'm getting

Comment: Can you add the complete error description in the code snippet

Comment: Try importing import java.io.File;

Comment: This is the Error                                                                                                               Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 FILE cannot be resolved or is not a field
 The method copyFile(java.io.File, java.io.File) in the type FileUtils is not applicable for the arguments (com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.file.File, com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.file.File)
 The constructor File(String) is not visible

 at Gmail_login.main(Gmail_login.java:22)

Comment: Please remove this line import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.file.File;

Comment: Ya i removed thankuuu now only one error is there: FILE cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: Did you take a look at the code in my answer?

Comment: You cannot just use a random import. Your imports are pointing to a similar but incompatable object. import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.OutputType;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.file.File;

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a Java programming question, not a testing question.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the work :

```
 import java.io.File;  
    import java.io.IOException;  
    import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;  
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;  
    import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;  
    import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;  
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;  
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;  
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;  
    import org.testng.annotations.Test; 

    public class Gmail_login {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http:\\google.com");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("D:\\google.png"));

        driver.quit();
        driver.close();

    }

}
```

Alternatively take clue from this question on how to take screenshot using Java : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/take-a-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 0):

```
      public void getscreenshot() throws Exception 
      {
              File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
              //The below method will save the screen shot in d drive with name "screenshot.png"
              FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("D:\\screenshot.png"));
      }
```

Comment: Hi Varun. Welcome to SQA. Code only or one liners are discouraged here. It would be good if you can add some description in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code and it is working fine, you can try the same.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;


public class Gmail_login {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get("http:\\google.com");
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

         try{
                //take screenshot and save it in a file
                File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

                //copy the file to the required path
                FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot,new File("C:\\Dhiman\\Automation\\screenshot.png"));

            }
         catch(Exception e){
                //if it fails to take screenshot then this block will execute
                System.out.println("Failure to take screenshot "+e);
         }  
    }
}
```